# CRC32 of binary string/binary data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc32

I want to get CRC32 of string which contains binary data. 
I tried to use somethink like this:

```
binascii.crc32(binascii.a2b_uu(my_binary_string))
```

But it often throws exceptions for larger strings.
Example content for my binary string:

```
my_binary_string = "0100101010..."
```

It can be really long.
How can I do this ?

Comment: you need a hex output right?

Comment: Hex output is ok, I think I can convert it to whatever I need.

Comment: what is the maximum length of binary data?

Comment: `binascii.crc32(binascii.b2a_hex('10000101010101001'))`;
`Out[10]: 945985288`

Comment: binascii.crc32(binascii.b2a_hex(my_binary_string)) : TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Comment: whch version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajay's answer is incorrect as it treats the binary data as a literal string - each 1 or 0 gets encoded into a separate byte.

Assuming your data is binary from UTF-8 encoding or just bytes concatenated into a long string, you should instead do something like this:

```
import binascii
data = '0110100001100101011011000110110001101111' # 'hello' encoded in UTF-8
int_arr = [int(data[i:i+8], 2) for i in range(0, len(data), 8)] # split the data into 8-bit chunks
print(hex(binascii.crc32(bytes(int_arr))))

# output = 0x3610a686
```

which will encode each 8 bits of the string correctly.

Answer (score 1):

for python 3
your binary in python3 should be `b'10001'`, should be prefixed with `b` or `B` to denote bytes literal:

```
In [11]: a=b'10000011110'

In [17]: hex(binascii.crc32(a))
Out[17]: '0xfc8e2013'
```